# symonfy/doctrine, get associated entity return null , but return actual data if a call to `dump()` is added

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, php-7

This is one is a bit weird

I'm using symfony3/php7

I have the following ProUser entity linked to a Organization entity, used to identity pro account, (important part is the "isEnabled" method), when I try to login with a ProUser that has a linked Organization (they all have, but I made triple sure to choose one that had in database), I got an error that the organization is null, but if i had a `dump` method to debug, then the organization is correctly retrieved from database by doctrine...

```
/**
 * Represent a professional owner (i.e a theater owner etc.)
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="pro_user")
 */
class ProUser implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id

     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Organization", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="legalRepresentative")
     */
    private $organization;
    public function getOrganization()
    {
        return $this->organization;
    }

    public function setOrganization(Organization $organization)
    {
        $this->organization = $organization;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Note: needed to implement the UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
    // for AdvancedUserInterface
    public function isEnabled(): bool
    {
        $organization = $this->getOrganization();
        // when this line is not present,
        // it throws an exception that $organization is null,
        // no problem when this line is present
        dump($organization);
        return $organization->isValidated();
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The stacktrace :

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError:
Call to a member function isValidated() on null

  at src/AppBundle/Entity/ProUser.php:151
  at AppBundle\Entity\ProUser->isEnabled()
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/AbstractToken.php:277)
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken->hasUserChanged(object(ProUser))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/AbstractToken.php:101)
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken->setUser(object(ProUser))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ContextListener.php:176)
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener->refreshUser(object(RememberMeToken))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ContextListener.php:109)
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener->handle(object(GetResponseEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Debug/WrappedListener.php:46)
  at Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\WrappedListener->handle(object(GetResponseEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Debug/TraceableFirewallListener.php:35)
  at Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener->handleRequest(object(GetResponseEvent), object(RewindableGenerator))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall.php:56)
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/EventListener/FirewallListener.php:48)
```

Is it due to the code happening in the Security Component, and the entity was unserialized instead of being retrieved by doctrine, so that getOrganization() does not yet return a doctrine proxy ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of Doctrine's lazy loading of relations (it basically only knows the primary ids of the connected entities untill one or more of them are called, like with dump()).

You can add the fetch attribute to your mapping, where `LAZY` is default, you can set this to `EAGER`.

Comment: yes but in other cases like this, the returned object is a doctrine proxy object, containing only the id, but not null, no ?

Comment: Hmm you're right, I had the same issue once, I'm not sure exactly what caused it but maybe I can help you if you post the code of the Organisation (or at least the mapping annotations etc.)? It is a bidirectional relationship so the annotations for $legalRepresentative should be like this: 

`@OneToOne(targetEntity="ProUser", inversedBy="organization") @JoinColumn(name="pro_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")`

(column names could be different ofcourse)